# Can't attach file to MessageEmbed when replying to interaction

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have been trying to reply to an interaction in discord.js with an embedded message which has a thumbnail attached.

This is the code I have been using:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const p = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'static', 'SDGs.json');

module.exports = (msg, int, text, sDGNo) => {
    fs.readFile(p, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err.message);
        }

        const db = JSON.parse(data);
        if (Number(sDGNo) === 0) {
            const imgFilePath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'static', 'SDGIcons', 'SDG_Wheel_Transparent_WEB.png');
            const imgAttachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment(imgFilePath, 'SDG_Wheel_Transparent_WEB.png');

            const goals = [];

            for (let i = 1; i < 18; i++) {
                const sdg = db[i];
                goals.push({ name: `${i} ${sdg.shortForm}`, value: `${sdg.shortFormJap}\n${sdg.shortFormNep}`, inline: true });
            }
            const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle('Sustainable Development Goals')
                .setColor('#ffffff')
                .setThumbnail('attachment://SDG_Wheel_Transparent_WEB.png')
                .addFields(goals)
                .setFooter('To find out more about each goal, simply type "!sdg" and the goal number (e.g., "!sdg7").');

            msg ? msg.channel.send({ embeds: [embed], files: [imgAttachment] }) : int ? int.reply({ embeds: [embed], files: [imgAttachment] }).catch(console.error) : null;
            return;
        }
    })
}
```

The function is executed in the handler for the interactionCreate event in a switch statement here:

```js
const { nE, tJ, say, whatis, spellcheck, joke, syn, ant, tN, sdg } = require('../helpers/commands');

module.exports = (client, interaction) => {
    switch (interaction.commandName) {
        /* ... */
        case 'sdg':
            sdg(null, interaction, null, interaction.options.data[0] ? interaction.options.data[0].value : '0');
            break;
    }
};
```

It works fine when it is used to send an embedded message with a message generated by the messageCreate event, but with an interaction created by the interactionCreate event, unless I exclude the files property in the reply options (in which case it posts the embedded message *without* the thumbnail image), I get the following error:

```js
DiscordAPIError: Unknown interaction
at RequestHandler.execute (D:\Discord\TranslationBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:298:13)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async RequestHandler.push (D:\Discord\TranslationBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:50:14)
at async CommandInteraction.reply (D:\Discord\TranslationBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:97:5) {
    method: 'post',
      path:'/interactions/895529028163878952/aW50ZXJhY3Rpb246ODk1NTI5MDI4MTYzODc4OTUyOlJ5YXRuSXZDekk3MFdyUzg3Z2RNZTB3U0ZpaVl4dlJkZjBySHRaYk05RDNwRE5pM1dTUG52eTR2aG9TUGl1QkVMOEt4aEhzRjNTTXdDS3dWZjNOaWtrMFZVQUlHWWkxOEJOUkY3eExFWk9xM3htWlFad2UzcWU5cnJnODVwZzc2/callback',
      code: 10062,
      httpStatus: 404,
      requestData: { json: { type: 4, data: [Object] }, files: [ [Object] ] }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can we see the part of your index.js where you execute this?

Comment: @MrMythical, it's the line here:
```msg ? msg.channel.send({ embeds: [embed], files: [imgAttachment] }) : int ? int.reply({ embeds: [embed], files: [imgAttachment] }).catch(console.error) : null;
```

Comment: That’s not the index.js. Where do you *execute* this function?

Comment: @MrMythical, I've updated the question with what I hope is the relevant information. It's the handler function I assign to the "interactionCreate" event in my main file. I also forgot to mention that the interaction reply works as long as I do not include the files property in the reply options. I hope that makes things clearer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are replying to the interaction too late.
The cooldown time is 3 seconds and if you do not reply after 3 seconds of the interaction creation, you would get this error.
Omitting the `files` property should not cause a problem.
Try deferring the reply first, then after that edit the reply.

```js
int.deferReply();
// ...
int.editReply({ embeds: [embed] });
```